# Generic labels in fviz_famd_ind instead of using rownames

Tags: ggplot2, label

I am trying to do a plot of individuals using fviz_famd_ind function in factoextra. I want my graph to label the individual data points with the row names from the data table I imported. However, it is adding generic numeric labels ("1","2", "3" etc.) instead.

My data table looks like this (plus 80 or so more columns):
[image]

When running:

```
fviz_famd_ind(res.famd_2, col.ind = "contrib",
              gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
              repel = TRUE)
```

I get a plot with generic numbers as my individual data labels.
[image]

I want the labels to be the row names seen in the table above. I'll note that I did set these row names via:

```
rownames(data_2022) <- c("Control","High pH 1","High pH 2","High pH 3", "High pH 4")
```

This was done before running the FAMD function.

I have been following the tutorial found here:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/115-famd-factor-analysis-of-mixed-data-in-r-essentials/

The graph of individuals in this example shows the row names as the labels and I am unsure why mine is not working.